OQS Provider loading issue in Android client
I have compiled openssl liboqs and oqs provider for my android client and put the .so files in jniLibs according to there architecture and also I have put the openssl.cnf file in the assets folder in my project directory and made the suitable changes to use oqs provider but my oqs provider is not getting loaded.
I'm using this function to check whether kyber is loading or not (This function return 0 and 1)
SSL_CTX_set1_groups_list(ctx, "kyber1024");
I have tried manual loading of oqs provider it is getting failed.
I also tried to setevn "OPENSSL_MODULES","LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ,"OPENSSL_CONF" but it is not helping me
if anyone know something how to load oqs provider in android please do let me know
Thanks in advance
